# How can I use PlatformIO with ESP8266 Arduino library git version?

Tags: arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266, platformio

I can use PlatformIO with official stable ESP8266 Arduino library.

However, I'd like to use PlatformIO with the git version of this library (the latest version available). How can I achieve that?

I tried inspecting boards json files but without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
platformio platform install https://github.com/platformio/platform-espressif8266.git#feature/stage
```

Set platform to espressif8266_stage in *platformio.ini*

```
[env:nodemcuv2]
platform = espressif8266_stage
board = nodemcuv2
framework = arduino
```

[origin](http://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/platforms/espressif8266.html#using-arduino-framework-with-staging-version)